# Is there an app which allows sharing of an iPad screen to another iPad?

Tags: ipad, sharing, screen

Is there an app that lets me share one iPad screen to another iPad when both are in the same location?

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially use something like [Reflector](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/) to mirror one iPad to a computer and then use a VNC client on the other iPad to view the computer, but I've never heard of any iPad-iPad direct sharing.